# Why can only one texture display correctly on my model?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv

hope everybody's well and staying safe. Complete Blender rookie here. I was hoping for some help troubleshooting an error I encountered in Blender 2.83 while trying to assign image textures to a head model I extracted from a video game (Mass Effect 3).

So this head model has four materials: eyelashes, face, scalp, and eyes. For some reason, only one material's texture ever displays correctly -- the other three just display as a random solid color.

I've tried restarting from scratch a few times, and one thing I've noticed is that the texture always displays correctly for the first material I assign an image texture to. Any material I attempt to assign a image texture to after the first material displays as a random solid color.

Here's a screenshot of the issue, if helpful. In this instance, I assigned a texture to the face material before all the other materials, so it's the only one that displays correctly:

[image: Image of error]

Also, here is the blend file as well (with all the textures packaged in), if anybody wants to investigate the issue directly: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R_Yn7RfQlKksQDSbEfTezUdB4iAYeJkL/view

This is how the character is supposed to look normally: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wqtK.jpg

Thanks in advance to anybody who's willing to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell from looking from your file, the only affected area is the hair (now that I look again, maybe the eyes too), which seems to lack a UV map. I selected the section and did a crude "sphere projection" unwrap and was able to get a texture on it.

[image: Unwrap1]

[image: Unwrap2]

The problem is, that when I connect the texture that came with it, it's not clear how it's supposed to be oriented. I tried several different unwrap methods, as well as different placements in the UV space, but I couldn't get it to line up in anywhere close to a satisfying fashion. Maybe you will have better luck than I.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at the file for me!

I seemed to remember a few attempts where it was instead the scalp/hair texture that displayed correctly when I assigned it a texture first, but the face texture just showed up as solid black when I tried texturing it afterwards.

I just tried again now, though, and it seems your observation is correct -- now the face texture always works but the other textures never work no matter the order I assign them in. Weird, maybe I changed something in the file without knowing it in between my attempts? (cont. in next comment)

Comment: In any case, I'm guessing you're right that it has something to do with the UV maps not importing correctly. I think I've tried redoing the UV maps from scratch before, but like you, unfortunately I haven't had any luck figuring out the projection lol. Not sure how I'll get the textures right...but in any case, thanks again for checking it out!

Comment: No problem. If it's worth anything, the best results I got were from unwrapping by selecting the area and just choosing plain "unwrap". When I moved it certain ways, you could see where the scalp is supposed to blend into the hair, but I don't know what to do with the "neck" area. There is a hole in the image if I move it around which I assume lines up with the empty "face area" but the correct orientation still eludes me.